# Two textboxes need to get the value set when Purchase option is selected from the drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text boxes enclosed in a . These two boxes are hidden when Purchase option is selected from the above drop down. Since, i am using required for these two boxes it is not passing the validation step when Purchase option is selected.
Question: How i set the values for the two text boxes i.e. PropertyValue and ExistingLoanBalance when Purchase option is selected from the drop down?

```
<select id="selectPR" name="selectPR" required>
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="Purchase" id="Purchase">Purchase</option>
        <option value="Refinance" id="Refinance">Refinance</option>
    </select>
    <div class="PR">
    <label for="PropertyValue" id="PropertyValue" >Existing Property Value*</label>
    <input type="text" id="PropertyValue" name="PropertyValue" class="PropertyValue" required>
    <label for="ExistingLoanBalance" id="ExistingLoanBalance">Existing Loan Balance*</label>
    <input type="text" id="ExistingLoanBalance" class="ExistingLoanBalance" name="ExistingLoanBalance" required>

    </div>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @Rotimi How i set the values for the two text boxes when Purchase option is selected from the drop down?

Comment: please explain the question and one example for better understanding.

Comment: @JustIn Added the question, please let me know if it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with the hidden condition of the text boxes by the following jquery as

```js
$("select").change(function(){
var value = $(this).val();
if(value == 'Purchase'){
 $("#PropertyValue,#ExistingLoanBalance").css("display", "none");
}
else{
$("#PropertyValue,#ExistingLoanBalance").css("display", "block");
$("#ExistingLoanBalance,#PropertyValue").prop("required",true);
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="selectPR" name="selectPR" required>
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="Purchase" id="Purchase">Purchase</option>
        <option value="Refinance" id="Refinance">Refinance</option>
    </select>
    <div class="PR">
    <label for="PropertyValue" id="PropertyValue" >Existing Property Value*</label>
    <input type="text" id="PropertyValue" name="PropertyValue" class="PropertyValue" >
    <label for="ExistingLoanBalance" id="ExistingLoanBalance">Existing Loan Balance*</label>
    <input type="text" id="ExistingLoanBalance" class="ExistingLoanBalance" name="ExistingLoanBalance" >
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE:** And do not mention required before in the input tag.Jquery will do its work.

Comment: I used your suggestion including the information from the NOTES but it seems not working. After doing the changes i do not see required validation for the two text boxes when i select the Refinance option from the drop down

Comment: ohh! ok one sec i'll add to my answer some extras.

Comment: if mentioned before hand remove all the properties of hide and reqired

Comment: Now can you see it?

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I tried the revised solution and  i do not see required validation for the two text boxes when i select the Refinance option. Since, i removed the required attribute from the two text boxes, it passing the validation.

Comment: So if it helped you can you please accept it as an answer

Comment: I am sorry. It did not solve the problem since required attribute does not work in either case i.e. Purchase and Refinance. As i mentioned, i removed the required attribute from the text boxes but the script is not taking care of it on case basis.

Comment: Ohh! i'm sorry i forget to set the property to true now i have checked it it is working don't worry.check out the edited code.

Comment: To see the working example for you code with submit button https://jsfiddle.net/rn6h02gq/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214542/discussion-between-user2852960-and-kunal-raut).

Comment: Your code is full done you can see it in the discussion room.

Comment: @user2852960 could you please upvote if you are able too.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, both of your input fields have same "id" as well as their labels, Id's should be different for them

You don't want to set the values of both text fields when Purchase option is selected but instead, you don't want to validate them using required atttribute. In summary, the required attrbute should be toggled based on the selection in dropdown

you can do it using onchange event of select box

```
<select id="selectPR" name="selectPR" required>
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="Purchase" id="Purchase">Purchase</option>
        <option value="Refinance" id="Refinance">Refinance</option>
    </select>
    <div class="PR">
    <label for="PropertyValue" id="lblPropertyValue" >Existing Property Value*</label>
    <input type="text" id="PropertyValue" name="PropertyValue" class="PropertyValue" required/>
    <label for="ExistingLoanBalance" id="lblExistingLoanBalance">Existing Loan Balance*</label>
    <input type="text" id="ExistingLoanBalance" class="ExistingLoanBalance" name="ExistingLoanBalance" required/>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#selectPR').on('change', function() {
    if( this.value == 'Purchase'){
       $('#PropertyValue').removeAttr('required');
       $('#ExistingLoanBalance').removeAttr('required');
    }
    else {
       $('#PropertyValue').attr('required', 'required');
       $('#ExistingLoanBalance').attr('required', 'required');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Note: I have changed the Id's of input fields in your HTML and same Id's are used in the jquery code

Comment: I corrected the IDs. It is not removing the attribute when Purchase is selected.

Comment: what's happening with Purchase option is selected? how did you verify whether the "required" attribute is being removed or not? I copied the same code in the jsFiddle and it's working OK [link](https://jsfiddle.net/48jds01r/), more details will be useful to get better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the ID's on your input tags are the same, I have updated this, you should revise them (although the ID's weren't used in my solution) to fit your preferences.
The simple solution to this is to change the display property of those input boxes whenever the value of the dropdown is equal to "purchase" as so:

```js
var selectPR = document.getElementById("selectPR");
var prop = document.getElementById("propvalue");
var loan = document.getElementById("existloanbalance");
var PR = document.querySelector(".PR")

selectPR.onchange = function() {
  if (selectPR.value == "Purchase") {
    PR.style.display = "none"
    loan.removeAttribute("required")
    prop.removeAttribute("required")
  } else {
    PR.style.display = "block"
    loan.setAttribute("required","")
    prop.setAttribute("required","")
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="selectPR" name="selectPR" required="">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Purchase" id="Purchase">Purchase</option>
  <option value="Refinance" id="Refinance">Refinance</option>
</select>
<div class="PR">
  <label for="PropertyValue" id="PropertyValue">Existing Property Value*</label>
  <input type="text" id="propvalue" name="PropertyValue" class="PropertyValue" required="">
  <label for="ExistingLoanBalance" id="ExistingLoanBalance">Existing Loan Balance*</label>
  <input type="text" id="existloanbalance" class="ExistingLoanBalance" name="ExistingLoanBalance" required="">
</div>
```

Comment: Will it pass the validation when the text boxes are hidden when Purchase option is selected?

Comment: That can be accomplished by using the remove attribute method, it should pass it now as I've edited the answer